# Can you use IS NOT NULL and a Wildcard as search parameters

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to query a table and I can't find an answer to my question. Is it possible to find a value that is not null and by using a wildcard statement?

```
 SELECT POSITION_TITLE, FNAME, LNAME, EMAIL,
FROM person_detail
WHERE POSITION_TITLE IS NOT NULL;
   (SELECT POSITION_TITLE, FNAME, LNAME, EMAIL, 
   FROM person_detail
   WHERE POSITION_TITLE LIKE ('ELE%'));
```

This is two different queries I do not know how to do this.

Comment: yes, just use the `LIKE`, since it will filter `NULL`s anyway

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use:

```
SELECT POSITION_TITLE, FNAME, LNAME, EMAIL, 
FROM person_detail
WHERE POSITION_TITLE LIKE '%'  -- will match anything that is NOT NULL
```

Comment: Why not just use `WHERE POSITION_TITLE IS NOT NULL` then?

Comment: @scsimon Because the question was `Is it possible to find a value that is not null and by using a wildcard statement` But in general I agree that `IS NOT NULL` is more readable.

Answer (score 1):

If i understand correctly, you just can put together like that

```
SELECT POSITION_TITLE, FNAME, LNAME, EMAIL
FROM person_detail P
WHERE (POSITION_TITLE IS NOT NULL AND 
       POSITION_TITLE LIKE 'ELE%');
```

However, you can directly express this as

```
SELECT POSITION_TITLE, FNAME, LNAME, EMAIL
FROM person_detail P
WHERE POSITION_TITLE LIKE 'ELE%';
```

Comment: This works but checking for not null is redundant. There are no values that are like ELE and NULL. ;)